# Adding C++ symbol links for framework?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, frameworks, protocol-buffers

I have a framework that references Protocol Buffer (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview). This seems to be causing me trouble whenever i stick the framework inside of an iOS app.

For example, i'm seeing this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"google::protobuf::Message::ParseFromIstream(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >*)", referenced from:
something(char const*) in MyFramework(myfile.o)
```

whenever i try to run my ios app.

Why does this happen? if i am able to build a framework, shouldn't that include all of the dependencies already? (such as protobuf).

i even tried to add the location of my homebrew installed Protobuf to the `Search Library Paths` in my project's build settings.

How do include protobuf in either my ios app or the framework?

Comment: Do you use the source code of protocol-buffers or something pre-compiled and built? It will probably be better if you'll add to the question some information about your build process.

Comment: i think so -> the source code is included in the framework. but it's not pre-compiled.